# PHP header(location: ...) redirect to more than one page

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to redirect a user to different pages, using PHP location header, depending on the page he came from?

I have multiple HTML forms all over my website that perform the same deleting action when I click on the submit button. And I also have multiple PHP files for each HTML form where the only difference is the location header url.

```
header('location:file.php');
```

Is there a way to have only one PHP file which redirects to the previous page or something?

Comment: Sure. Check the `$_SERVER` array for a referrer.

Comment: Are you using a framework? If so, which one?

Comment: yes, there's many ways. some more reliable than others.

Comment: use conitional statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone! Here's my final code:

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents you from passing a $string-variable to header, thus redirecting to multiple locations with the same statement. You could use a $_SESSION-Variable to store some parameter that controls where you want to redirect to.

But with all the broadness you asked, it is hard to give more detailed answers...